# Samba and verifying server identity

Tags: identity, identity-theft, smb, samba

Suppose that I have two Windows 10 (Professional edition) computers, one (PC) sharing a folder and second one (notebook) copying data to the shared folder automatically. I would like to prevent notebook from copying the data to unknown/fake servers accepting any passwords/credentials. Is there some security in the protocol (SMB version 3.1.1, possibly with encryption enabled) with regards to verifying endpoint identity or preventing using a fake server, when it does not know the user name and password pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in your situation.

When you want the client and the server both to verify each other's identity, this is called "mutual authentication".

Per [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2017/05/26/smb-2-and-smb-3-security-in-windows-10-the-anatomy-of-signing-and-cryptographic-keys/), NTLM does not support mutual authentication. (It's the third bullet point in the NTLM SessionKey section.)

Kerberos supports mutual authentication, but you must setup a Windows domain to use Kerberos authentication. This requires a Windows Server OS.

After that, the client must be configured to require mutual authentication once both systems are joined to the domain---mutual authentication is not required by default even when it is available.